# Java To Pascal Example

Tags: java, pascal

I'm new to programming and I don't understand Java at all. Below there's code in Java that I can't figure out in Pascal:

```
public static boolean verificaRS(String numeroRS)
{
    Integer numeroAbsoluto = Integer.valueOf(0);
    Integer resto = Integer.valueOf(0);

    Integer numero = Integer.valueOf(0);
    int numeroAuxiliar = 1000000000;
    int soma = 0;

    try
    {
        numero = Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(numeroRS));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Log.escreveLog(ex.toString());
       return false;
    }

    if (numero.intValue() > 0)
    {
        for (int contador = 9; contador > 1; contador--)
        {
            numeroAuxiliar /= 10;
            resto = Integer.valueOf(numero.intValue() % numeroAuxiliar);
            numeroAbsoluto = Integer.valueOf(numero.intValue() / numeroAuxiliar);
            numero = Integer.valueOf(numero.intValue() - numeroAbsoluto.intValue() * numeroAuxiliar);
            soma += numeroAbsoluto.intValue() * contador;
        }

        if (soma % 11 == numero.intValue())
            return true;

        if ((soma % 11 == 10) && (numero.intValue() == 0))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Somebody can help me translate? So far this is what I did:

```
NumeroAbsoluto, Resto, Numero, NumeroAuxiliar, Soma: Integer;
Contador: Integer;

begin
  numeroAuxiliar := 1000000000;
  Numero := 00009356332;

  for Contador := 9 downto 1 do
  begin
    NumeroAuxiliar := NumeroAuxiliar div 10;
    Resto := Numero mod NumeroAuxiliar;
    NumeroAbsoluto := Numero div NumeroAuxiliar;
    Numero := Numero - NumeroAbsoluto * NumeroAuxiliar;
    Soma := Soma + NumeroAbsoluto * Contador;
  end;
```

The numero in this case is 00009356332. But in the end, the result is not the same.

Comment: Maybe you could add some details about what you were thinking was going to happen, compared to what did happen? Often just writing down the question will help you figure out the solution!

Comment: Sorry for that. I forget to explain. In the end theres in java (soma % 11 == numero.intValue()). I put Soma:=soma mod 11; and the if soma=numero, returns true. So i have a comparison between soma and numero.

Comment: In java theres this line: numero = Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(numeroRS)); This number is 00009356332, just to simplify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following (interleaved to illustrate what's translated). The key issue with the translation you show so far is that your `for contador :- 9 downto 1` should be `downto 2` to match what the original code does.

```
//public static boolean verificaRS(String numeroRS)
//{

function verificaRS( numeroRS: string ): boolean;

//    Integer numeroAbsoluto = Integer.valueOf(0);
//    Integer resto = Integer.valueOf(0);
//    Integer numero = Integer.valueOf(0);
//    int numeroAuxiliar = 1000000000;
//    int soma = 0;
var
    numeroAbsoluto: integer = 0;
    resto: integer = 0;
    numero: integer = 0;
    numeroAuxiliar: integer = 1000000000;
    soma: integer = 0;

//    try
//    {
//        numero = Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(numeroRS));
//    }
//    catch (Exception ex)
//    {
//       Log.escreveLog(ex.toString());
//       return false;
//    }
begin
    try
        numero := StrToInt( numeroRS );
    except
        // This is basic; there is probably a smarter way to handle the exception
        Log.escreveLog( "StrToInt exception" );
        exit( false );
    end;

//    if (numero.intValue() > 0)
//    {

    if numero > 0 then
    begin
//        for (int contador = 9; contador > 1; contador--)
//        {
//            numeroAuxiliar /= 10;
//            resto = Integer.valueOf(numero.intValue() % numeroAuxiliar);
//            numeroAbsoluto = Integer.valueOf(numero.intValue() / numeroAuxiliar);
//            numero = Integer.valueOf(numero.intValue() - numeroAbsoluto.intValue() * numeroAuxiliar);
//            soma += numeroAbsoluto.intValue() * contador;
//        }

        for contador := 9 downto 2 do
        begin
            numeroAuxiliar := numeroAuxiliar div 10;
            resto := numero mod numeroAuxiliar;
            numeroAbsoluto := numero div numeroAuxiliar;
            numero := numero - numeroAbsoluto * numeroAuxiliar;
            soma := soma + numeroAsboluto * contador;
        end;

 //       if (soma % 11 == numero.intValue())
 //           return true;
 //
 //       if ((soma % 11 == 10) && (numero.intValue() == 0))
 //       {
 //           return true;
 //       }
 //
 //       return false;

        verificaRS := ((soma mod 11) = numero) or (((soma mod 11) = 10) and (numero = 0));
 //}
end;
```